# Show that $(\nabla G)(x_{0},y_{0}) = \lambda (\nabla F)(x_{0},y_{0})$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $F,G\colon \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. Also let $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)\neq 0$. Let $M:= \{(x,y): F(x,y)=0\}$. G has relatively to M a local maximum at $(x_{0},y_{0})\in M$ ($\exists  U(x_{0},y_{0})\implies \forall (x,y)\in U \cap M: G(x,y)\leq G(x_{0},y_{0})$. Show with the Implicit Function Theorem: $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}: (\nabla G)(x_{0},y_{0}) = \lambda (\nabla F)(x_{0},y_{0})$.

We are one hour into this topic and I don't know, how I should do this, so help is really appreciated.